# Using the words "collision" ,"clash" and "strike"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, word-difference

Which one of the following verbs can make a better sense in my self-made sentence and sounds more natural:

> - It is believed that the ................ **of** an asteroid or a meteor **to** The Earth has extinguished the dinosaurs' **race**.

a) collision
b) clash
c) strike

Based on dictionaries, all these words have the potential of being used in this sense, but I don't know what would be a native speaker's choice here. I wonder if you could help me with this question and let me know if there is a more common word in such an occasion.

Comment: As a general comment, not related to this question only: you should use a spell checker when writing. That will help you learn the correct spelling of words. Some browsers even have spell-checker(s) integrated, so you will not need additional tools installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When discussing about asteroids or meteors hitting other celestial objects (including Earth), the right word is **"collide"** / **"collision"**.

Comment: Then using the word "collision" my sentence is natural @virolino?

Comment: Yes, in your sentence "collision" is the best word.